# Symfony 2 FOS Bundle Installation

Tags: symfony, installation, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to install the FOS bundle on a Debian server. I use the vendor script and I get the following error :

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
Cannot import resource "/var/www/Symfony/app/config/parameters.ini" from "/
var/www/Symfony/app/config/config.yml".
```

Any idea what could be causing this ?

Comment: Does the file exists, and is it syntactically correct ?

Comment: Solved. Just a missing end quote in parameters.ini

Answer (score 1):

Hope OP already solved this problem from his comment. But I give explanation for future googlers.

This error is due to `invalid yml` file content. Check your **parameters.ini**, You can validate YML file using [online tool](http://yamllint.com/).

I got this problem because wrong usage of yml in [symblog tutorial](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/validators-and-forms.html#configure-swift-mailer-settings). I changed `mailer_transport="smtp"` into `mailer_transport: "smtp"` to solve my issue.